# twitter regular expressions

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, twitter, adobe

I need 3 different regular expressions

- one that finds at the beginning of the string a 'D' and a space then a name, so 'D patrickgates hello there' would return 'D patrickgates', or if all possible would return just 'patrickgates'
- one that will find the @ sign and a name together anywhere in the string so '@patrickgates hello, world' would work and return '@patrickgates' or if at all possible would return just 'patrickgates'
- one that will find 'RT' and a space and then '@' and the username at the beginning of the string so 'RT @patrickgates' would work

if returning just the username and also being true isn't possible with one regex, then I could use one to match to, and one that will delete the 'D' or the '@' or the 'RT', thank you

(fyi, i'm using AS3 to do this)

Comment: for future reference checkout this great tool for creating regular expressions http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `D patrickgates` use `^D (\w+)` to capture 'patrickgates'
2. `@patrickgates hello, world` use `^@(\w+)` to capture 'patrickgates'
3. `RT @patrickgates` use `^RT @(\w+) to capture 'patrickgates'

If you want a single regex to capture `patrickgates` from all three of your examples:

`^(?:D |@|RT @)(\w+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function convertTwitterMsg (o:Object):void {
   trace('New Tweet: ' + o);
   var original:String = o.title;
   _tweet = original.replace(/(^|\s)@(\w+)/g, "$1@<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/$2\">$2</a>");
   _final = _tweet.replace(/(^|\s)#(\w+)/g, "$1#<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$2\">$2</a>");
   ta.htmlText = _final;
}
```

ta should be the id of your mx:TextArea, you could also use spark, but it changed the way you style your text in spark.
_tweet is a String

I copied pasted the function, use at your own convenience.